# How do I add figure and figcaption type tags in Magento?

Tags: html, magento

Every time I add these two

```
<figcaption> or <figure>
```

HTML5 tags into the editor it removes them and inserts P tags.  I am using Magento CE 1.7.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To support html5 in Magento pls install this extension

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/meanbee-tinymce-html-5-compatibility.html

In order remove the `"<p>"` you have to set some options in the TinyMce at js/meanbee/tinymce5/setup.js around line 100 add this

```
        force_br_newlines : false,
        force_p_newlines : false,
        forced_root_block : '',
```

Hope it will help